# I can't get MySQL Fulltext search to work

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a table that stores lists of postal/ZIP codes:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `postal_codes` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `codes` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `codes` (`codes`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

INSERT INTO `postal_codes` (`id`, `codes`) VALUES
(1, '30301\r\n30302\r\n30303'),
(2, '90001\r\n90002\r\n90003\r\n90004\r\n90005');
```

I need to check whether a certain row contains a certain postal/ZIP code. However, it doesn't work. For example, this query returns the row with an ID of 2 although the 'codes' column doesn't contain 'dfgdfgdfgdf'. Why is that?

```
SELECT *
FROM postal_codes
WHERE MATCH(codes) AGAINST('+dfgdfgdfgdf' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND id='2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FULLTEXT` is notorious for working strangely on small tables. You might try populating your postal-code table with a few thousand rows of non-repetitive test data before you give up on it.

(I assume you've thought of normalizing the data in your postal-code table, so there's one row per postcode. That's a much more robust way of handling the kind of numeric-token search you're trying to do.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You're right, I've thought of normalizing the data. Using fulltext search would be an easier way to do what I'm trying to do in my application, but now that I know that it's not that reliable, I think I will normalize the data after all.